# Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Atom on Windows

Tags: windows, julia, atom-editor, juno-ide, julia-pkg

I am having endless loop

```
(v1.1) pkg> update Atom
  Updating registry at `C:\Users\Dmitry\.julia\registries\General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Juno [e5e0dc1b]:
 Juno [e5e0dc1b] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.5.0-0.5.5, 0.6.0, 0.7.0-0.7.2, 0.8.0-0.8.4] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions 0.5.4 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.5.4
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Atom [c52e3926] to versions: [0.6.0, 0.7.0-0.7.2, 0.8.0-0.8.4] — no versions left
   └─Atom [c52e3926] log:
     ├─possible versions are: [0.8.0-0.8.8, 0.9.0-0.9.1, 0.10.0-0.10.2, 0.11.0-0.11.3, 0.12.0-0.12.27] or uninstalled
     └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.8.0-0.8.8, 0.9.0-0.9.1, 0.10.0-0.10.2, 0.11.0-0.11.3, 0.12.0-0.12.27]

(v1.1) pkg> update Juno
  Updating registry at `C:\Users\Dmitry\.julia\registries\General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Atom [c52e3926]:
 Atom [c52e3926] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.8.0-0.8.8, 0.9.0-0.9.1, 0.10.0-0.10.2, 0.11.0-0.11.3, 0.12.0-0.12.27] or uninstalled
 └─restricted to versions 0.7.14 by an explicit requirement — no versions left
```

How to understand this message and how to overcome it? On linux it worked.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Julia v1.1? The current release is 1.5.3, updating might solve the problem.

Comment: @NilsGudat I was not realizing that, thanks

Comment: Did that do the trick?

Comment: @NilsGudat it did :)